# overwrite arguments while bind multiple dynamic jqgrid

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, jqgrid

I have below code for binding jqgrid. I have multiple jqgrid in my page.
i bind all dynamically through below code.

```
var MyGridData = MyGridData || (function() {

return {
   init : function(Args) {
       _args = Args;
  },
initiateGrid: function() {
  this.fillGridSchema(_args[6]);
 },
fillGridSchema : function() {
   $('#' + _args[0]).jqGrid({

       //All basic code for binding jqgrid (url,colnames...)

   });
 }
}
```

When i want to bind my SalesInquiryDetails Grid, then i call below code.

```
MyGridData.init([ 'SalesInquiryDetails',...(other required args) ]);
MyGridData.initiateGrid();
```

if i want to bind SalesReferenceGrid then,

```
MyGridData.init([ 'SalesInquiryReference',...(other required args) ]);
MyGridData.initiateGrid();
```

Now, i got _args of last bind grid every time. And not getting events which i have defined for previous grid.

Please guide me.
How can i fire previous grid event functions given in previous args array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, i got _args of last bind grid every time.

Right, because you have only one `_args` variable, which is a global. Your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) by assigning to an undefined symbol in loose mode, which reaches out and creates a global variable. One of JavaScript's major flaws, which was fixed by strict mode in 2009. (I strongly recommend using strict mode.)

In order to have more than one `_args`, you'll probably want `init` to return something (an object), store `_args` on it, and then call `initiateGrid` on that object. Your singleton can only remember the last state you set, so don't make it a singleton.

One way you might do that would be to use a standard constructor function:

```
var MyGridData = MyGridData || (function() {
    function MyGridData(args) {
        this.args = args;
    }
    MyGridData.prototype.initiateGrid = function() {
        this.fillGridSchema(this.args[6]);
    };
    MyGridData.prototype.fillGridSchema = function(/*shouldn't you be using an arg here, since you pass one in `initiateGrid`?*/) {
        $('#' + this.args[0]).jqGrid({
            //All basic code for binding jqgrid (url,colnames...)
        });
    };

    return MyGridData;
})();

// Usage
var salesDetailsGrid = new MyGridData([ 'SalesInquiryDetails',...(other required args) ]);
salesDetailsGrid.initiateGrid();

var salesInquiryGrid = new MyGridData.init([ 'SalesInquiryReference',...(other required args) ]);
salesInquiryGrid.initiateGrid();
```

Or with ES2015:

```
let MyGridData = MyGridData || (function() {
    class MyGridData {
        constructor(args) {
            this.args = args;
        }
        initiateGrid() {
            this.fillGridSchema(this.args[6]);
        }
        fillGridSchema(/*shouldn't you be using an arg here, since you pass one in `initiateGrid`?*/) {
            $('#' + this.args[0]).jqGrid({
                //All basic code for binding jqgrid (url,colnames...)
            });
        }
    }

    return MyGridData;
})();

// Usage
let salesDetailsGrid = new MyGridData([ 'SalesInquiryDetails',...(other required args) ]);
salesDetailsGrid.initiateGrid();

let salesInquiryGrid = new MyGridData.init([ 'SalesInquiryReference',...(other required args) ]);
salesInquiryGrid.initiateGrid();
```

But JavaScript is flexible, there are lots of other ways, such as factory functions.

Note: The code above is merely meant as an *example*, it's not meant to represent tested or thoroughly-reviewed code.

Comment: sorry what is the meaning of ES2015?

Comment: @Jaykishan: The latest version of the JavaScript specification, more technically the ECMAScript specification, is [ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html), released June of last year. So ES2015 is the latest, ES5 (ECMAScript 5) is the one before that (2009), and ES3 (1999) is the one before that. (There was no ES4.) Browsers are working to support all of the new features in ES2015. Some, like the latest Chrome, are very close. But of course, legacy browsers never will.

Comment: where i should declare args?

Comment: @Jaykishan: Again, you can't do it with just one `args`. That's why I showed the solution above with an object.

Comment: I am not getting this.args inside  $('#' + this.args[0]).jqGrid({
                //All basic code for binding jqgrid (url,colnames...)
            }); i want to call function name dynamic on events of jqgrid. like loadcomplete : function() {  var fn = window[_args[2]];  if (typeof fn === 'function') { fn(); } }

Comment: can i use this.args in gridcomplete inside $('#' + this._args[0]).jqgrid({...}) ?